# capybara /cucumber can't find radio

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm having an issue finding a radio button. Here is a snippet of the html:

```
<form action="/" id="frm-info" method="post"><input id="ClickedButton" name="ClickedButton" type="hidden" value="" /><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="KTQF3bkKPP0OirvtL1EYsW-Q77zq-8H9YAPqeoBB9ewpNSYoc0dOEout26qrtMmX6xBx0_roxqWRwCXAlwZRTyW9ZBTBjwNgifWqws6hyOFIRmc6O-7P6jZXbZNYJ5Pazt9Hmg2" />    <div class="row borGreyPad mlmrcolor bb0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 coverImage">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 fr xs-fl">
                <div class="frm-content axaborderBlue mt10">
                    <div class="pl25 pt15 pr15 pb10">
                        <p class="large-heading">Enter some basic information to get started</p>
                        <div class="row ">
                                <div class="row pl15">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 r xs-l mb5 f14">Application Taken: *</div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 mb5">
                                        <div class="groupBox">
                                            <span class="dib f14 ">
                                                <input id="ApplicationTaken" name="ApplicationTaken" tabindex="1" type="radio" value="ApplicationInPerson" /><span class="dib mr10 ">In Person</span>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="dib f14 ">
                                                <input id="ApplicationTaken" name="ApplicationTaken" tabindex="2" type="radio" value="ApplicationByPhone" /><span class="dib mr10 ">By Phone</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
```

I want to select the radio button with name "ApplicationTaken" and value "ApplicationInPerson"

I've tried several different ways including:

When I click on the radio with name

```
"([^"]*)" and value "([^"]*)"$/ do |myName, myValue|
  choose("#{myName}", :option => "#{myValue}")
end
```

and

When I click on the radio with name

```
"([^"]*)" and value "([^"]*)"$/ do |myName, myValue|
    find(:xpath, "//input[@value='#{ myValue }']", match: :first).set(true)
end
```

I keep seeing the following error:

```
"Unable to find radio button "ApplicationTaken" with value "ApplicationInPerson".
```

I've also tried by `ID`, no luck. I CAN select a button on this page and fill in text fields, I just can't select radio buttons or drop downs. Thanks

Comment: You really need to clean that up. `When /^| click`? That's totally unreadable garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using capybara try:

```
choose('Visible Text')
```

See:

https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105

Comment: Still no luck, that was an option I tried originally but tried it again just to be sure, still cannot find it.

Comment: Choose('By Phone') isnt found? Hmmm

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have two radio buttons with the same id. This is bad - you should not have duplicate ids on a page. Attempting to find an element by ID when there are duplicates is very unpredictable.

What's most likely happening is that it's finding the first element with a matching ID, and then checking the value attribute. When that doesnt match, it says the element could not be found, because it does not continue onto the next matching ID (because of the way id selectors work internally)

I see you're also using xpath to find the element. You generally should be using CSS instead of xpath for finding your elements.

So leaving the ID out, and using CSS instead, `find('input[name=ApplicationTaken][value= ApplicationInPerson]')` should get you the element you're looking for.

Comment: Still didn't work...getting:
"Unable to find css "radio[name=ApplicationTaken][value=ApplicationInPerson]" <Capybara::ElementNotFound>

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant the following: `input[name=ApplicationTaken][value= ApplicationInPerson]` Note that this is an input element, not a radio element. I'll update the original comment too in case anyone stumbles upon this for help.